# Why cant I use LINQ in my views?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2

The model being passed to my view is of type `tblUser` - so I expected that I would be able to:

```
<% Model.tblLogins.Where(l => l.date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)).Count() %>
```

However, the `.Where()` part is not available as an option? I have the following in my `web.config` but hasnt helped:

```
    <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
    <add namespace="System.Data.Linq"/>
    <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
```

Has anyone had this problem before? Thanks for any assistance :)

Comment: What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: Is tblLogins an IQueryable? I use Linq in Views (yes, I know it's bad) without a problem.

Comment: @Marcelo: The LINQ properties of any IQueryable object are not available

Comment: @Lazarus: You're right, it is bad, but its in a report so I'm letting it slide! :) Yes, tblLogins is IQueryable, its a table from my database generated by LINQ-to-SQL

Comment: I was fending off others who were likely to pull me up on it rather than chastising you ;) Can you post your controller action that's being used to determine the Model for the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
Uninstall Resharper 5!

Really sorry to have wasted everyone's time - as it turned out, the views actually worked fine with the LINQ in there, its just that Resharper wasnt picking up the references. I only installed Resharper 5 about three hours ago - guess that didnt last long - back to Telerik JustCode :P